# Failed to show selected image from gallery in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to choose image from gallery and load or show it in the activity. But the code is not working properly. It can only select image from the phone gallery but doesn't show the selected image. Checking the logcat got these errors.I'm providing the java file, xml file and manifest below.

```
11-15 16:31:23.795 18921-18921/com.example.emma.gallaryview E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
11-15 16:31:34.970 18921-18921/com.example.emma.gallaryview E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20171114_202150.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

java file

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }

}
```

The xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
        android:text="Load Picture" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

and manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.emma.gallaryview">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android 6+ you have to add code to ask the user of your app to confirm the permissions you requested in manifest.

Google for runtime permissions.

Further your code is much to complicated. You should just open an input stream for the obtained uri and then let bitmap factory decode from the steam.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

Then use

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is).
```

Finally: dont be surprised if decodeStream returns null on a lot of devices. Well as decodeFile would.

Comment: Or, better yet, use an image-loading library, such as Picasso or Glide.